# java different way of writing initialisation and method call

Tags: java

I was thinking about something. Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Maintain {

  public Maintain(Thing t) {
    //do whatever is needed here
  }

  public void registerChange() {
    //some implementation
  }

}
```

The purpose of maintain doesn't really matter since it is just something I have made up, lets just assume it maintains things/objects and `registerChange()` was just to notify some other class that something has happened.

now lets say we want to use that method, we would do something like this:

```
Maintain m = new Maintain(t);
m.registerChange();
```

where `t` is some object that is of the right type expected by the constructor.

My question is whether there are different ways of writing the declaration and method call, like in one line of different ways of making the call along with initialisation.

Comment: like calling `registerChange()` inside the constructor maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the method call in the constructor:

```
public Maintain(Thing t) {
  //do whatever is needed here
  registerChange();
}

public void registerChange() {
  //some implementation
}
```

and then just do:

```
Maintain m = new Maintain(t);
```

Comment: I did think about it, but then lets say that we don't want the method to be compulsary when Maintain is created?

Comment: Then you can add a boolean parameter to the constructor, so that the method is invoked when the parameter is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm understanding but :
You could make `registerChange` send back the instance

```
public Maintain registerChange() {
  //some implementation

  return this;
}
```

Then use chaining :

```
Maintain m = new Maintain(t).registerChange();
```